# What is the proper way to change the default email validation error message?

Tags: validation, email, parsley.js

Using *parsley.js*, what is the proper way to change the email error validation message from
`"This value should be a valid email."` to `"That's not a valid email. Check again?"`

Couldn't find a simple way in the docs, examples or online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom message in the html element itself.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-error-message="YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE HERE" required="">
```

**Sample usage:**

[image]

Refer: [Online Documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-for-field)